# Why is my R^2 value on python giving me a negative integer as output?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to simply calculate an `R2` value using `Sklearn function r2_score`, however, when I run it on the below dataset (`df total N=3,000`), I get an `R2` of `-19.46`. I feel like this should be simple, but am not sure what may be going wrong.

```
   expected  predicted    
1    0.0009  0.013639         
2    0.0003  0.016178          
3    0.0072  0.042318          
4    0.0354  0.511545          
5    0.0029  0.395005
```

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

r2 = r2_score(df['expected'], df['predicted']) 
print('r2 score is', r2)
```

Comment: `from sklearn import metrics` does not make available a function name `r2_score` - `metrics.r2_score` perhaps, but the function you're calling is not coming from that import. Please edit the code to make it a [mcve].

Comment: r2_score could be negative

Comment: Fair point @SiAce. However, from my understanding the R2 should only fall between 0 and 1. Is there no lower bound to negatives?

Comment: Don't be fooled by the square (which is misleading indeed). By definition, `R^2 = 1 - \frac{RSS}{TSS}`, which has no guarantee that `R^2` is non-negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a symmetric function.

Unlike most other scores, R^2 score may be negative (it need not actually be the square of a quantity R).Best possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model can be arbitrarily worse).